# Problem related to convergence of a series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

**Problem**

> Determine whether the given series is convergent or not:
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\log\left(n\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)$$

**Attempt**

Checking for absolute convergence

$|\sum_{1}^{\infty}\log(n\sin(\frac{1}{n}))|=|\sum_{1}^{\infty}(\log(n(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{-1}{n^3 3!}+...)))|
=|\sum_{1}^{\infty}(\frac{-1}{n^2 3!}+\frac{-1}{n^4 5!}+...)|
=|\sum_{1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{n^2 3!}-\frac{-1}{n^4 5!}+...)|$

Comparing with $\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$ , the series converges absolutely

> Is this correct?

Comment: You ask if 'function is convergent or not', then talk about some series. Please clarify whether you are interested in  a sequence or  a series.

Comment: Oh my bad . Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is correct but we don't need to use absolute convergence, we have indeed that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\log\left(n\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\log\left(1-\frac1{6n^2}+O\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)\right)=-\frac16\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n^2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}O\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)$$

and both series converge.

Answer (score 1):

Errors:

1. The second "$=$" sign is wrong. We do not have $|\log (1+x)|=|x|$ unless $x=0.$

   2. $\log (n\sin 1/n)=\log (1-d)=-(d+d^2/2+d^3/3+...)$ where $d=1/3!n^2-1/5!n^4+-...$

It suffices to observe that  $0<d<1/3!n^2<1$ when $n\in \Bbb N,$ as the terms in the series for $d$ are alternating and diminishing, so that $0<d+d^2/2+d^3/3+...<d+d^2+d^3+...=$  $=d/(1-d)<d/(1-1/3!n^2)\leq d/(1-1/3!)<(1/3!n^2)/(1-1/3!)=O(1/n^2).$

It would be better if you edited to say " the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\log (n\sin 1/n)$ " in the first line.

Comment: You had the right idea but the devil is in the details.

Comment: I think it is not clear. I am expanding $\log(1-x)$ and not considering the higher order terms.